# Camel 3 - Predicate Calling Method on Bean Stored as ExchangeProperty

Tags: java, apache-camel-3

With Camel 2 it was possible to call a method on a bean stored as exchange property like so when building a predicate:

```java
exchangeProperty("aPropertyHoldingABean").method("aMethodReturningAString").in("a", "b")
```

In Camel 3 the `method` method has been removed and I am not able to figure out how to achieve something comparable. E.g.

```java
method(exchangeProperty("aPropertyHoldingABean"), "aMethodReturningAString").in("a", "b")
```

fails because the `BuilderSupport::method` tries to call the method right on the `ValueBuilder` instance returned by `exchangeProperty(String)` instead of evaluating the builder first.

What is the (idiomatic) way to build a predicate with Camel 3 that uses the return value of a bean stored as an exchange property?